# Can't change default .jar opener from Command Prompt to Java SE Binary

Tags: windows-7, windows, jar

A while back I changed my default opener for `.jar` files to cmd, as I was writing a few console applications in java and wanted to be able to run them easily (I now know that you can a similar result via `javaw.exe`). I am now trying to switch the default opener back to `javaw.exe`, as I'd done this before. I was unable to change it to `javaw.exe` or any other program, suggested or otherwise.

I couldn't do it via right clicking and going through Open With --> Choose Default Program... menus. This approach opened the program with `javaw.exe`, but failed to set it as the default opener. I tried also to do it through Control Panel, but this failed to change the default opener as well. Finally, I followed the tutorial [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/why-cant-i-change-my-default-zip-application/753fc3a6-0250-46bd-8ed2-5de671c69ead?msgId=5190ab8c-d9e7-42fb-a3fb-37cf70af664b), but I couldn't find "No File Associate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to uninstall and then reinstall Java (in hopes it resets the file associations)

If still not working try pressing Windows Key + R and paste 
"Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations"

Set it to **`java.exe`** not `javaw.exe` (Can't remember which one runs java but it's worth a shot.

Even if that doesn't work try a System Restore point from before the associations. (Make one before you restore incase you need to revert)

If that still doesn't work check this article out:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html

or other tutorials from the internet. Please backup before making changes if something goes wrong (system restore point)

Comment: If you go to use the Sevenforums tutoral you'll need a .reg file
I might be able to make one if needed.

Comment: Thanks! The second solution worked(I had 7 different java associated programs, uninstalled two of them, then decided it was a bit risky). Note, I found the program in `Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Default Programs` and had to change it to WinRar. I then used the traditional `Open With --> Choose Default Program...` approach

Comment: As long as it worked, ;)